# Use mutual recursion to solve a combinatorial game

Tags: sml, combinatorics, game-theory

It is a typical impartial game. Two players take turn to pick sticks which are labeled from 1 to n, and whenever No.1 stick gets picked the game is over. Rules are simple: PlayerA counts down to 5 and pick the correspondent stick; PlayerA counts up to 2 and pick the correspondent stick. The program is trying to find an initial point such that No.1 stick will be last picked.

I try to loop over the list and find which initial position will give the satisfying result, but it seems to returning value is not right. What's wrong with the codes??

```
fun play(stick) = 
let 
    val stick_list = n_list(stick) 
    (*n_list(8) will generate an int list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]*)

    fun playerA(x::nil, n) = x
      | playerA(stick_list, n) = 
            let 
                val pos = (n + (5 mod size(stick_list))) mod size(stick_list)
            in
                playerB(delete(stick_list, pos), pos)
            end
    and playerB(x::nil, n) = x
      | playerB(stick_list, n) = 
            let 
                val pos = (n + (~2 mod size(stick_list))) mod size(stick_list)
            in
                playerA(delete(stick_list, pos), pos)
            end
    fun search(n) = if playerA(stick_list, n - 1) = 1 then n + 1 else search(n - 1)
in
    search(stick - 1)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- `n_list` is easily implemented as `List.tabulate (stick, fn i => i + 1)`.
- Use `length` rather than `size` when working on lists.
- Consider remembering the number of sticks left, so the length does not need to be recalculated. E.g.

  ```
  fun play nSticks = 
      let val allSticks = List.tabulate (nSticks, fn i => i + 1)

          fun playerA ([stick], _, n) = stick
            | playerA (sticks, sticksLeft, n) =
              let val pos = (n + (5 mod sticksLeft)) mod sticksLeft
              in
                playerB (delete (sticks, pos), sticksLeft - 1, pos)
              end
          ...
  ```
- Unless this is an exercise in mutual recursion, it seems that you can avoid repeating yourself a lot if you combine the two player functions into one, e.g. by

  ```
  datatype Player = PlayerA | PlayerB
  fun player (_, stick::_, 0) = stick
    | player (player, sticks, sticksLeft, pos) = ...
      let val (newPos, otherPlayer) =
              case player of
                  PlayerA => ((n + 5) mod sticksLeft, PlayerB)
                | PlayerB => ((sticksLeft + n - 2) mod sticksLeft, PlayerA)
          val newSticks = delete (sticks, pos)
      in player (otherPlayer, newSticks, sticksLeft - 1, newPos) end
  ```

Comment: But this is not really the problem.

Comment: I suppose you meant that "This is not what is mainly wrong with the problem". You need to be able to explain what is actually wrong with the code, rather than "it doesn't work" to be able to get the feedback you expect. With [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) you are not only able to express what is wrong with your code in a concise way (the reader of your test will know exactly what to expect), but the process of writing a test will give insight into what could go wrong.